# show $\omega$ is exact form

Tags: differential-geometry

Let X be the region $\mathbb{R^3}-(0,0,0)$ and f(x,y,z) is $C^\infty$ function on X. Also $\omega$ is 1-form $f(x,y,z)(xdx+ydy+zdz)$. if $f$ can be expressed in the form $f(x,y,z)=h(r)$ when $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ then show

(1) $\omega$ is exact form on X. (ie. there exists $C^\infty$ function $g$ satisfy $\omega=dg$ )

(2) in (1) if $\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2g}{\partial z^2}=0$ then express $g$ in form of $x,y,z$

(1) I can show $\omega$ is closed form and $\omega=h(r)dr$ but still cannot show that it is also exact

thanks for your help

Comment: No. In fact, $w=h(r)rdr$ not $h(r)dr$ as $rdr = xdx+ydy+zdz.$ Maybe, that's the source of confusion!

Comment: what's $\int h(r)rdr?$

Answer (score 1):

The space $X=\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{(0,0,0)\}$ has $H^1(X)=0$, and so every closed $1$-form is exact.

The same argument can be stated without mentioning cohomology groups. There is a bijection between $1$-forms and vector fields, given by $dx\mapsto e_1,dy\mapsto e_2,dz\mapsto e_3$. Note that by this isomorphism, a $1$-form is closed if and only if the corresponding vector field is *locally conservative*, whereas it is exact if and only if the corresponding vector field is *conservative.* Since the space $X$ is simply connected, every locally conservative vector field is conservative, thus every closed $1$-form is exact.

Comment: I don't think, OP knows cohomology! I'd rather use a simpler argument.

Comment: @ Ehsan M. Kermani I added some alternative way to say the same thing. Have a look if you wish.